Dice Sum Game Strategy

Suppose we play a game with two dice where we roll and
sum our rolls. We can stop any time and take the sum as our score, but if we roll a sum we’ve rolled
before then we lose everything. What strategy will maximize our expected score?

I tried brute forcing this and enumerating all possibilities and still couldn't come up with the correct strategy. Can someone help me solve this question? Are there any shortcuts/tricks to solving this?
I cannot understand the solution provided in the pdf from where I got this problem and it goes as follows:
Let C be our current score, and S be the set of sums rolled so far, so:
$$
C = \sum_{i \in S} i.
$$
Let p(i) be the probability of rolling a sum of 'i' with a single roll of two dice.
To maximize our expected score, we should stop rolling if the expected score after rolling again is less than our current score. That is:
$$
\left( \sum_{i \in S} p(i) \cdot 0 \right) + \sum_{i \notin S} p(i)(C + i) < C.
$$
This simplifies to:
$$
\sum_{i \in S} p(i)(C + i) > 7.
$$
When does this occur? After a single roll ( r ), the stopping condition is:
$$
2rp(r) > 7.
$$
Since the left-hand side maxes out at r = 7, with, $$ 2r \cdot p(r) = \frac{7}{3} $$ We should always roll at least twice.
One can check as well that, after two rolls, the left-hand side of (3.21) is at most:
$$
\frac{247}{36} \approx 6.861 < 7,
$$
so we should always roll at least three times (if we can).
After rolling three times, there are many sets ( S ) for which we should stop. We should stop after three rolls if any of the following are true:

$ \{ \{6, 7\}, \{7, 8\}, \{7, 9\}, \{7, 10\}, \{8, 9\} \} \subseteq S $

$ 2 \notin S $ and $ \{ \{6, 8\}, \{6, 9\}, \{6, 10\}, \{7, 11\}, \{7, 12\}, \{8, 10\}, \{8, 11\} \} \subseteq S $

Current score is 28 or greater and $ S \notin \{5, 11, 12\} $

$ S \in \{ \{3, 9, 10\}, \{4, 5, 7\}, \{4, 5, 8\}, \{4, 6, 11\}, \{4, 8, 12\}, \{4, 9, 11\}, \{5, 8, 10\}, \{5, 10, 11\}, \{5, 6, 12\}, \{5, 7, 12\}, \{5, 9, 10\}, \{5, 9, 11\}, \{5, 10, 12\} \} $


After rolling four times, we should stop unless one of the following is true:
(a) $ \{2, 3, 4\} \subseteq S $ and $ 7 \notin S $
(b) $ S $ equals one of $ \{ \{2, 3, 5, 6\}, \{2, 3, 5, 11\}, \{2, 3, 5, 12\}, \{2, 3, 10, 12\}, \{2, 3, 4, 11, 12\} \} $
If we are lucky enough to roll five times, we should stop. With ( |S| = 5 ),
$$
\sum_{i \in S} p(i)(C + i)
$$
is minimal when ( S = {2, 3, 4, 5, 12} ), with the sum being:
$$
\frac{169}{18} \approx 9.389 > 7.
$$
If we apply this optimal strategy, the expected score will be:
$$
\frac{513389}{34992} \approx 14.671611.
$$
With this strategy, the smallest non-zero score that can be attained is 15, and the largest possible score is 39. The probability of zero is:
$$
\frac{217495}{629856} \approx 0.345309,
$$
and the most likely non-zero score is 21, occurring with probability:
$$
\frac{10109}{139968} \approx 0.0722237.
$$
Interestingly, instead of using this complex strategy, a very good and simple strategy is to always stop after three rolls. With this simple strategy, the expected score is:
$$
\frac{6265}{432} \approx 14.502315
$$
not that much less than the optimal strategy. The range of possible non-zero scores is 9 to 33. The probability of scoring zero is:
$$
\frac{401}{1296} \approx 0.309414
$$
and the most likely non-zero score is 21, as it is with the complex strategy, and this occurs with probability:
$$
\frac{277}{3888} \approx 0.0712449.
$$

Example for clarification: suppose I roll a sum of 9 on the first attempt, decide to roll again and get a sum of 7 on the second attempt. If I stop now I only get a score of 7?And if I roll again I would lose everything if the third roll shows either a sum of 7 or a sum of 9?



Suppose we play a game with a die where we roll and sum our rolls. We can stop any time and take
the sum as our score, but if we roll a face we’ve rolled before then we lose everything. What strategy
will maximize our expected score?


(Same as previous game, but with two dice.) Suppose we play a game with two dice where we roll and
sum our rolls. We can stop any time and take the sum as our score, but if we roll a sum we’ve rolled
before then we lose everything. What strategy will maximize our expected score?



I got this question from from "A Collection of Dice Problems" by Matthew M. Conroy, and this is exactly how it was written. I was able to solve Q72, but I have the same confusion as you in Q73.

@ShsTht the danger of just posting a problem verbatim is any ambiguity in the wording is preserved. The way the problem was interpreted by quarague (above) and ploosu2 (in the answers) - coincidentally, by me - is not the way the author of the book interprets it. Per the solution there, the scoring is cumulative; in fact, the optimal score per the given strategy is greater than $12$. So you've got an answer to a problem, but not the one the author intended. For reference: https://www.madandmoonly.com/doctormatt/mathematics/dice1.pdf

This can be solved with recursion. It is a Markov Decision Process and generally we could use value iteration or policy iteration to solve it but here the underlying graph is acyclic and we can solve the max expectation recursively from the leaf nodes where it is known.
Introduce the states $(t, s)$ where $t$ is the indicator vector of what sums we have already rolled and $s$ is the currently rolled sum. And define $E(t,s)$ to be the maximum expectation starting from the state $(t,s)$ and following the best strategy. If $t_s = 1$, then $E(t,s)=0$. Otherwise it is
$$
E(t,s) = \max(s, \sum_{j=2}^{12} p_{j}E(t_2, j))
$$
where $t_2$ is $t$ with the $s$'th component changed to $1$.
In the beginning of the game we don't have a currently rolled sum, so we have to take one step and the maximum expectation of the game is thus given by (here $\large{1_j}$ denotes the vector where $j$'th component is $1$ and all other are $0$)
$$
\sum_{j=2}^{12} p_{j}E({\large{1_j}}, j).
$$
Sage-code for this recursion (generalized to $k$ dice with $D$ faces):
def calcE(D=6, k=2):
    ps = [0]*(k*D-k+1)
    N = len(ps)
    for ds in cartesian_product([range(1,D+1)]*k):
        ps[sum(ds)-k] += 1/D**k
    #print (ps)

    def fillPlace(t, i):
        return tuple(t[j] if j!=i else 1 for j in range(N))

    memo = {}

    def E(t, s):
        #print ("E(%s, %s)" %(t,s))
        if (t,s) in memo: return memo[(t,s)]
        place = s-k
        #print ("place = ", place)
        if t[place]==1: return 0
        eReroll = sum(ps[j]*E(fillPlace(t, place), j+k) for j in range(N))
        ret = max(eReroll, s)
        memo[(t,s)] = ret
        return ret

    ret = sum(ps[j]*E((0,)*N, j+k)  for j in range(N))
    #print (memo)

    return ret


%time ans = calcE(D=6, k=2)
print ("%s = %f" %(ans, ans))

It gives the answer $\frac{45325201}{5668704} = 7.995690$ and the strategy can be read out from the memo dictionary: at each state $(t,s)$ if $E(t,s)>s$, then reroll, otherwise take $s$.

UPDATE
If the score is cumulative, we can introduce another variable $S$ to the state and compare with it. And make it cumulative. The code:
#The cumulative score case
def calcE(D=6, k=2):
    ps = [0]*(k*D-k+1)
    N = len(ps)
    for ds in cartesian_product([range(1,D+1)]*k):
        ps[sum(ds)-k] += 1/D**k
    def fillPlace(t, i):
        return tuple(t[j] if j!=i else 1 for j in range(N))
    memo = {}
    def E(t, s, S):
        memoKey = (t,s,S)
        if memoKey in memo: return memo[memoKey]
        place = s-k
        if t[place]==1: return 0
        eReroll = sum(ps[j]*E(fillPlace(t, place), j+k, S+j+k) for j in range(N))
        ret = max(eReroll, S)
        memo[memoKey] = ret
        return ret

    ret = sum(ps[j]*E((0,)*N, j+k, j+k)  for j in range(N))

    return ret


%time ans = calcE(D=6, k=2)
print ("%s = %f" %(ans, ans))

It gives the answer
$$
\frac{513389}{34992} = 14.671611
$$

I added the cumulative case. Btw, I forgot to write the max in the definition of recursion of E (in the code it was OK).

Minor nitpick, but did you do this in Sage? In vanilla python, your cartesian_product function would not be defined by default, so it would produce an error I think.  (And if it did run, the calculations would be done using floating-point arithmetic rather than exact fractional arithmetic, by default.)  So it might be better to say that you have posted Sage code, rather than Python code, even though of course the syntax is very similar.

@mathmandan Yes, it's Sage. We could take product function from itertools. Or better yet, calculate the dice sum probabilities directly not using brute-force : ).
